# Match version-dependent enum value from external library

Tags: rust

#### TLDR: In a `match` statement, is it possible to *explicitly* handle `enum` variants that might not exist? (due to differing external library versions)

I am writing some code for a library that uses a `match` statement to handle the conversion of an object from a different library.

This object comes from the `geo-types` library, where a `geo_types::Geometry` can represent one of several types of objects:

```rust
pub enum Geometry<T> 
where
    T: CoordinateType, 
 {
    Point(Point<T>),
    Line(Line<T>),
    LineString(LineString<T>),
    Polygon(Polygon<T>),
    [...]
}
```

(each of these structs are defined elsewhere in `geo-types`)

This other library (`shapefile`) implements a `TryFrom` trait to convert certain `geo_types::Geometry` variants into variants of the the library's own `shapefile::Shape`, which is a similar enum:

```rust
pub enum Shape {
    Point(Point),
    Polyline(Polyline),
    Polygon(Polygon),
    [...]
}
```

The conversion is done in other traits, so the `try_from()` function basically tries to match compatible variants of each enum in a match block. Every possible `geo_types::Geometry` variant is explicitly matched with a `Shape` variant.

```rust
match geometry {
    geo_types::Geometry::Point(point) => Ok(Shape::Point(point.into())),
    geo_types::Geometry::Line(line) => Ok(Shape::Line(line.into())),
    [...]
}
```

But in version 0.6.0 of `geo-types`, there are 2 new variants of the `Geometry` enum introduced: `Rect` and `Triangle`. That `match` statement now will not compile:

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `Rect(_)` and `Triangle(_)` not covered
   --> src/record/mod.rs:464:15
    |
464 |         match geometry {
    |               ^^^^^^^^ patterns `Rect(_)` and `Triangle(_)` not covered
    | 
   ::: /home/roger/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/geo-types-0.6.0/src/geometry.rs:39:5
    |
39  |     Rect(Rect<T>),
    |     ---- not covered
40  |     Triangle(Triangle<T>),
    |     -------- not covered
    |
    = help: ensure that all possible cases are being handled, possibly by adding wildcards or more match arms
    = note: the matched value is of type `geo_types::Geometry<f64>`
```

I can't handle these explicitly, or else I break compatibility with older versions of `geo-types`:

```
error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `Rect` found for enum `geo_types::Geometry<_>` in the current scope
   --> src/record/mod.rs:479:34
    |
479 |             geo_types::Geometry::Rect(_) => { 
    |                                  ^^^^ variant or associated item not found in `geo_types::Geometry<_>`
```

I could do a wildcard match `_ => { Err("Unrecognized Geometry") }`, which compiles for both the new and old versions of `geo-types`, although it does give a warning if you try to compile with an older version of `geo-types`:

```rust
warning: unreachable pattern
   --> src/record/mod.rs:480:13
    |
480 |             _ => { // New geometries Rect(_) and Triangle(_) added in 0.6.0
    |             ^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default
```

But I can annotate with `#[allow(unreachable_patterns)]`. This works for now, but suppressing a warning seems like a bad code smell. Additionally, it seems like implementing a conversion of `Rect` or `Triangle` will require breaking compatibility with certain versions of `geo-types` (which in turn breaks compatibility with other geographic libraries that rely on `geo-types`).

Is there a way to optionally handle these new enum variants in a way that does not depend on their existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To answer your question*: no, it is not, at least not without something as primitive and finnicky as version-based [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) (which may not even be possible). You could try some fancy enum discriminant related magic (which might only work for fieldless enums anyway), but it isn't worth the cost.

*To solve your problem*: You will be better off not worrying about maintaining compatibility with older versions of `geo-types`, at least for now.

Generally speaking, it is ill-advised (and often impossible, as your issue demonstrates) for a specific version of a library to be compatible with multiple major versions of a dependency, as each major version is expected to introduce backwards incompatible changes. This is why libraries typically bump major versions for every major version bump in its dependencies -- those using a specific major version of a dependency will use the corresponding major version of the library.

Given that the `geo-types` API hasn't been stabilized yet (the major version is still 0), backwards incompatible changes may be introduced in *any* version. Attempting to support each and every one of these changes is just not worth the trouble. For instance, it is highly likely that there are a number of versions of `geo-types` that introduce a new variant in the `Geometry` enum -- will you go about trying to monkey-patch your code to support each and every one of these versions?

The best option for you is thus to just support the latest version. As is usually the case with development releases, others using the `geo-types` library will very likely use the latest version of `geo-types`; if not, they can just use the version of your library that supports their `geo-types` version. You aren't expected to do much with an unstable API in terms of backwards compatibility -- only when the public API is stabilized do you actually have to worry about releasing and supporting multiple major versions of your library for each major version of `geo-types`.